# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python and this could be a very simple type of error, but can´t work out what´s wrong. I am trying to get the links from a website containing a specific substring, but get the "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" when I do it. I believe the problem is related to the links I get from the website. Anybody knows what is the problem here?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html_page = urlopen("http://www.scoresway.com/?sport=soccer&page=competition&id=87&view=matches")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
lista=[]
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    lista.append(link.get('href'))

for text in lista:
    if "competition" in text:
        print (text)
```

Comment: `soup.find_all('a')` it's return `None` here.

Comment: @RahulKP `find_all`  does not return `None`. If there are no elements, it returns `[]`. Error is in another string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784582/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable)

Comment: Please post the __full__ traceback and the relevant code - nothing in your snippet does raise this exception (at least not with python 2.7.6 / bs 4.4.1).

Comment: Also note that `urllib.urlopen` returns a `addinfourl` object, not the page's html content. You may want to use the `python-requests` package instead of the low-level `urllib`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks, it is fixed with the answers below. Apparently some of the links were creating a non iterable list and that was the problem. I am quite new so didn´t know about python-requests so will have a look into it, many thanks!

Comment: Indeed, `if 'something' in None` does raise a TypeError with ''NoneType' is not iterable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `TypeError` exception because some 'a' tags dont have a 'href' attribute , and so `get('href')` returns `None` , wich is not iterable .

You can fix this if you replace this :

```
soup.find_all('a')
```

with this :

```
soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

to ensure that all your links have a 'href' attribute

Answer (score 1):

In the line `lista.append(link.get('href'))` expression `link.get('href')` can return `None`. After that you try to use `"competition" in text`, where `text` can equal to `None` - it is not iterable object. To avoid this, use `link.get('href', '')` and set default value of `get()` - empty string `''` is iterable.

Comment: Thanks! That also works and let me understand better the dimension of the problem in the list I was creating.

Answer (score -1):

I found mistakes in two places.

First of all the `urllib` module doesn't have `request` method.

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 # should be
 from urllib import urlopen
```

Second one is when you are fetching the link from the page, `beautifulSoup` is returning `None` for few link.

```
 print(lista) 
 # prints [None, u'http://facebook.com/scoresway', u'http://twitter.com/scoresway', ...., None]
```

As you can see your list contains two `None` and that's why when you are iterating over it, you get `"TypeError: 'NoneType'`.

How to fix it?
You should remove the `None` from the list.

```
  for link in soup.find_all('a'):
      if link is not None:  # Add this line
          lista.append(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Author uses Python3. In Python3 `urllib` has `request` and `request` has `urlopen`.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I am using Python 3 (in Spyder if that helps) and I need the urllib.request. Thanks anyway!